# Do we need to add html extension to partials?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, naming-conventions

Let we have a partial  `_form.html.slim`

It seems that there is no difference for rails add you the `html` extension or not so we can remove the `html` extension. `_form.slim` will be the same partial and works well.

Is there any difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Common format handling

The scheme for a template is : `<action_name>.<format>.<preprocessors>`.

Adding format extension is a mean to constrain template on that filetype, but it's totally optional, just like preprocessor.

If for example you were to implement a `foos/index.erb` template, it could be used to render either `http://host/foos`, `http://host/foos.json`, `http://host/foos.html` or whatever mime type you use. Using `foos/index.html.erb`, you specify this template should only be used for html.

Formats the template may be use for with no format constraint depends on :

- the use or not of `#respond_to` in your controller, forcing allowed formats
- the default recognized formats

There are quite [a bunch of default recognized mime types](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/http/mime_types.rb), as of now : html, text, js, css, ics, csv, png, jpg, gif, bmp, tiff, mpeg, xml, rss, atom, yaml, json, pdf, zip.

If you were to specify both a file name with format forced and a one without, the forced format template would take precedence for that given format (so, if you have `foos/index.html` and `foos/index`, the first one will be used to render html pages, while the second one will be used for any other format).

Note that since both format and preprocessor are optional, you could have just a `foos/index` file if you want. That would serve a static file (not preprocessed) for all default formats.

## With partials

The exact same rules apply to partials. If you specify a format, the partial will only be used for that format. You may specify multiple partials having each their format, and you can omit format to use the same partial for all formats.

Answer (score 0):

yes you may do it but that partial will be rendered as js and css as well. So if possible try to avoid it

Comment: What does 'rendered as js and css` mean?

Comment: if you want to feel why it is dangerous try to rename your application.html.erb as application.erb . Now though your views will be working, but all your remote request will not work now. Because all remote request for script are going to render application.erb in js

Comment: I know about it but the question was about _partials_

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure in this case, but html is the content type and slim would be the template engine. The filename.content_type.template_engine format separates it out to be processed. It may have worked for you to remove the html extension, but I believe it to be best practice to keep the extensions in place.